# How do I dump information quickly?

Tags: c, io, valgrind

I'm creating a Valgrind tool that generates some information about the frequency of function calls (specifically, how many instructions are executed between calls). Currently, I have my tool set up to write a short string to a dumpfile that includes the thread that is running, the number of instructions executed, the function entered, and the address of that function. I use the provided `fprintf` wrapper to do so.  For example, I might get a dump that looks like this:

```
1, 7363505897, (null), 4033bd
1, 1802196819, (null), 4033bd
1, 1800457355, (null), 4033bd
1, 1800903611, (null), 4033bd
1, 1801692437, (null), 4033bd
1, 1801040389, (null), 4033bd
1, 1801611746, (null), 4033bd
1, 1800840377, (null), 4033bd
1, 1801334975, (null), 4033bd
1, 1800615992, (null), 4033bd
1, 1800791120, (null), 4033bd
1, 1800710678, (null), 4033bd
1, 1801015823, (null), 4033bd
1, 1801594353, (null), 4033bd
1, 1801029625, (null), 4033bd
1, 1800482880, (null), 4033bd
```

In testing, however, I've discovered that when I try to run this for all functions, a significant portion of the information is not written to the file. For example, in my test application a function called `conj_grad` is executed 15 times. When I specifically instrument ONLY that function, all 15 executions show up in my dumpfile; when I instrument ALL functions, it only shows up once.

The conclusion I've come to is that I'm trying to write to disk far too often. Is there a (better) way to collect this information and write it to disk? I'm hesitant to create massive buffers in memory - the tool already sucks up 30+ GB on larger multithreaded programs - but it can be done if necessary.

Comment: `I'm trying to write to disk far too often`: Isn't the O.S expected to handle that correctly? Such things simply don't happen on sane systems.

Comment: @KemyLand - when it comes to operating systems, the one thing I've learned in grad school is that they're "expected" to guarantee many things, but in practice there's always a loophole/exception. Regarding my conclusion - I'm basing that solely on what I've seen thus far. I could be entirely wrong - wouldn't be the first time - but I don't know what else is causing the problem then.

Comment: Yes, OSes guarantee a lot of things that in practice they can't, such as avoiding out-of-memory situations. However, based on the theory/code I know with respect to OSes, unless you're using some rare gem, there's no such thing as "writing-to-the-disk-too-fast situation/error". The kernel can just pause your process if that is the case. After all, you *don't* write to the disk, but tell the kernel what to write to the file, then does the kernel/device-driver does the job. Everything fits well. Filesystems, block devices... Everything would get corrupted if that happened, and it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need massive buffers, but if you're writing to block based storage, writing in units smaller than the block size can be rather inefficient, though some smart disk controllers can mitigate some of the performance hit.

A reasonable way to do this would be to write to a buffer that you flush when it reaches a certain, relatively small size (e.g. a MB or so) *or* a configurable length of time passes (e.g. 1 second).

That way you will write many full blocks and probably a partial block, amortizing the partial-block write while reducing the amount of data that can be lost due to a crash to your time limit (e.g. 1 sec).

Comment: As @kemyland pointed out in their comment above - does my conclusion regarding the writing to disk even seem like a valid one? Or should I be looking elsewhere? Regardless - I'll definitely give this a shot.

Comment: The OS is handling writes to disk as correctly as possible. If you store things on block storage, it has to ensure the integrity of the whole block. If the block is already partially written to, the OS first has to read the contents of the block, then update them and flush the result back to disk.

Comment: This turned out to not be my exact problem (had to do with the use of global variables), but it was *a* problem. So I appreciate the answer!